# .NET Windows Forms - multiple connection strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, deployment, connection-string

I have a vb.net windows forms application. I am in development stage and i have a connection string stored in app.config working properly. The application will be installed to different clients each one having a different connection string.

How will I get/set the connection string of each client in order to connect to their local database? The connection string will be handled before or after deployment of the appliaction to the client?

Thanks.

Comment: If you cannot expect your user to edit the deployed App.config directly, the connection information is usually collected by a custom installer which will take over the task to write the connection string to the deployed App.config. Depending on the installer you choose some coding may be required.

Answer (score 0):

i have a different types of approach in mind, but it will be too long if i will discuss it all, so you can take the ideas and study it for yourself so you can grasp how to implement it.

1. You can store your connection string variables in a database and retrieve it base on who is your client.
2. You can create or find an existing server or webservice, they are the one who will get a request from your application and will return the specific connection string to your client application. This method is also good because it adds security, but the down side is that creating one is another study and will surely take time in development.
3. You can insert some kind of setting in your application where your user can choose the connection.
4. An ugly method is to give different application depending on your client with different connection string.

Hope you get an idea.

Comment: _1.You can store your connection string variables in a database_ How you connect to database without Connection String to retrive connection string?

Comment: You can create 1 connection string that points to a database where you store your client data and the other connection strings, then transferring them to another database by returning a new connection string, then your application should handle it.